# INNER JOIN multiple tables with same column name

Tags: php, mysql, inner-join

I am trying to get data from tables, using this query:

```
$query = "SELECT wplt_wpl_properties.mls_id, 
            wplt_wpl_properties.property_type,
            wplt_wpl_properties.location1_name,
            wplt_wpl_properties.price,
            wplt_wpl_properties.price_unit,
            wplt_wpl_properties.lot_area,
            wplt_wpl_properties.lot_area_unit,
            wplt_wpl_properties.build_year, 
            wplt_wpl_property_types.id,
            wplt_wpl_property_types.name,
            wplt_wpl_units.id AS units_id,
            wplt_wpl_units.name AS units_name
            FROM wplt_wpl_properties 
            INNER JOIN wplt_wpl_property_types 
            ON wplt_wpl_properties.property_type=wplt_wpl_property_types.id INNER JOIN wplt_wpl_units ON units_id=wplt_wpl_properties.price_unit";
```

HTML/PHP part

```
 <tr>
                    <td style="vertical-align: middle;"><?php echo $count; ?></td>
                    <td style="vertical-align: middle;"><?php echo $row['mls_id']; ?></td>
                    <td style="vertical-align: middle;"><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
                    <td style="vertical-align: middle;"><?php echo $row['location1_name']; ?></td>
                    <td style="vertical-align: middle;"><?php echo $row['price']; ?></td>
                    <td style="vertical-align: middle;"><?php echo $row['units_name']; ?></td>
                    <td style="vertical-align: middle;"><?php echo $row['lot_area']; ?></td>
                    <td style="vertical-align: middle;"><?php echo $row['lot_area_unit']; ?></td>
                    <td style="vertical-align: middle;"><?php echo $row['build_year']; ?></td>
                </tr>
```

But it doesn't show any results.

Comment: Have you tried to run the query directly. I mean does your query returns anything?

Comment: where $count and $row came from? Well, try to run this query directly from phpmyadmin and see what it shows

Comment: 1/ What does the query return? 2/ Is it all you get in your html / php? Where do you fetch result and create your row?

Comment: $count and $result are not mistakes. It shows Unknown column 'units_id' in 'on clause' in phpmyadmin

Comment: You have `wplt_wpl_units.id AS units_id` in your select and `units_id=wplt_wpl_properties.price_unit` in your ON clause, think last bit should be `id=wplt_wpl_properties.price_unit`

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
wplt_wpl_units.id AS units_id
```

in your select and

```
units_id=wplt_wpl_properties.price_unit
```

in your ON clause, the last bit should be

```
id=wplt_wpl_properties.price_unit
```

Answer (score 0):

I made mistake and didn't see it. Instead of `ON units_id=wplt_wpl_properties.price_unit` should be
`INNER JOIN wplt_wpl_units ON wplt_wpl_units.id=wplt_wpl_properties.price_unit`